# How do I create a delete button where I can delete the list at the side of my database?

Tags: javascript, php

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pK7x.png)

How do I create a delete button where I can delete the list at the side of my database?
I'm trying to get the 'x' or delete button as shown in the picture
This is  my current code:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/booklist.css">
  <title>Search data by its ID</title>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function out() {
      alert("Checkout Items Successful!");
    }
  </script>

</head>
<div class="background">
  <h1>Library Checkout System</h1>
  <h2>Loan/Request Your Books Here</h2>

  <form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="id" placeholder="Please enter Book ID" />
    <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search By ID" />

  </form>
  <table border="2" id="newton">
    <tr>

      <th>Product Name</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Returned Date</th>
    </tr><br><br>

    <?php
            $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "");
            $db = mysqli_select_db($connection,"myfirstdb");
            session_start();

            if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
                $_SESSION['id'] = array();
            }
            

            if(isset($_POST['search']))
            {
                $id = $_POST['id'];

                array_push($_SESSION['id'],$id); //Here we have declared a session array. We can add elements to it by array_push function.//
                $_SESSION['id'] = array_unique($_SESSION['id']); //array_unique: Removes duplicate values from an array


                $id = implode(',',$_SESSION['id']);  //implode : returns a strings from the elements of an array.//
         // instead of changing the database of each row, the implode() function adds the rows according to the selected id entered.//
         // this function is the key for solving my original problem.//    
               
               

                $query = "SELECT * FROM `table3` where id in ($id)";
                $query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run))
                {
                    ?>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <?php echo $row ['product_name']; ?> </td>
        <td>
          <?php echo $row ['quantity']; ?> </td>
        <td>
          <?php echo $row ['returned_date']; ?> </td>


      </tr>

      <?php

                }
            }


            ?>

  </table>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="send" value="Confirm Booklist" onclick="out()" />
  </form>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

How do I create a delete button where I can delete the list at the side of my database?
I'm trying to get the 'x' or delete button as shown in the picture

Comment: this data is generated dynamically??

Comment: @KUMAR I can enter the number from 1 to 21 through the "Search ID" Button and the database will automatically display. So, which means I set the database according to the ID entered